# Translate Toast message android studio

Tags: android, translation, toast, language-translation

Does anyone know to can I translate a toast message in android studio?
I don't know how to convert the string message into the resource file (String.xml) like a textview in android studio

```
String toastMessage1 = "Good Job! ";
String toastMessage2 = "Correct Answers";

if (dNumber >= 90) {

    Toast.makeText(
        MainActivity.this,
        toastMessage1 + String.valueOf(dNumber) + " % " + toastMessage2,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a string in your strings.xml

```
<string name="string_name">Good Job! %d Correct Answers</string>
```

Use String functions for updating string.

```
String.format(res.getString(R.string.string_name), dNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

You really should do your research first - it's quite simple, really. Read through [String Resources guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) - it has all the information you need.  In a nutshell, what you need is to add your text into the XML file as usual:

```
<string name="good_job">Good Job! %1$d %% Correct Answers</string>
```

Then you just use `getResources` and `getString`:

```
String toastMessage = MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.good_job, dNumber);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Do note that you need to have double-%, as the % char itself has special meaning inside the string and needs to be escaped.